# WooCommerce, different prices based on location

Tags: plugins

A client of mine is setting up an e-commerce store but instead of having straight currency conversions for their products ($99.99 = £65.70 for example) they want to be able to set specific prices based on the location of their customer ($99.99 for US customers, £99.99 for UK customers, etc.)

Now personally I wouldn't do it this way given the choice but they're keen on doing it, so is it possible with the WooCommerce plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The WooCommerce plugin, as of version 2.0, doesn't support such feature out of the box, but it's implemented by 3rd party plugins. I developed one of them, so I won't post the link here because it's not the right place for advertisement, but you can find the site in my profile.